# How can I get value from NumberPicker in another Activity to show on my textView in expendablelistview child

Tags: java, android, eclipse

```js
MY ADAPTER
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

 private Context _context;
 private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
 // child data in format of header title, child title
 private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;
 
 


  
 public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
   HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
  this._context = context;
  this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
  this._listDataChild = listChildData;
  
  
  
  
 }

 @Override
 public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
  return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
    .get(childPosititon);
 }

 
    
    
 
 @Override
 public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
  return childPosition;
 }

 @Override
 public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
   boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
  
  
  

  
  if (convertView == null) {
   LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
     .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
  }
  
  
  
  

  
  TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
    .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

  txtListChild.setText(childText);
  
  
  
    
 
  return convertView;
 }

 
 @Override
 public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
  return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
    .size();
 }

 @Override
 public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
  return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
 }

 @Override
 public int getGroupCount() {
  return this._listDataHeader.size();
 }

 @Override
 public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
  return groupPosition;
 }

 @Override
 public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
   View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
  
  if (convertView == null) {
   LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
     .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
  }

  TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
    .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
 
  
  
  
  lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
  lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

  
  return convertView;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean hasStableIds() {
  return false;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
  return true;
 }
 
}
```

```js
MY ACTIVITY CODE
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
 ExpandableListView expListView;
 List<String> listDataHeader;
 HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
 PopupWindow popUp;
 Dialog picker;
 Button edit;
 Button set;
 TimePicker timep;
 Integer hour;
 TextView time;
 Context context;
 

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.expendable);
  
  // get the listview
  expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

  // preparing list data
  prepareListData();

  listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

  // setting list adapter
  expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

  // Listview Group click listener
  expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

   @Override
   public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
     int groupPosition, long id) {
    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
    // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
    // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return false;
   }
  });
  

         
  
 
  // Listview Group expanded listener
  expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

   @Override
   public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
      listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
  });

  // Listview Group collasped listener
  expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

   @Override
   public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
      listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   }
  });
  
  // Listview on child click listener
  expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

   @Override
   public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
     int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    
    Toast.makeText(
      getApplicationContext(),
      listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
        + " : "
        + listDataChild.get(
          listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
          childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
      .show();
    
    
   
    
    
    Intent child0Intent = new Intent(getApplication(), Picktime.class);
    startActivity(child0Intent);
    return false;
    
   }
  });
  
  

   
   
   

   
   
  
  
  
 
 }

 /*
  * Preparing the list data
  */
 private void prepareListData() {
  listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
  listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
  

  // Adding child data
  listDataHeader.add("Light");
  listDataHeader.add("Television");
  listDataHeader.add("Computer");
  listDataHeader.add("Fan");
  listDataHeader.add("Aircondition");
  listDataHeader.add("Oven");
  listDataHeader.add("Refridgerator");
  listDataHeader.add("WaterHeater");

  // Adding child data
  List<String> Light = new ArrayList<String>();
  Light.add("Power:14w/hr");
  
 
  List<String> Television = new ArrayList<String>();
  Television.add("Power:0.03w/hr");

  List<String> Computer = new ArrayList<String>();
  Computer.add("Power:100w/hr");
  

  List<String> Fan = new ArrayList<String>();
  Fan.add("Power:75w/hr");

  List<String> Aircondition = new ArrayList<String>();
  Aircondition.add("Power:1000w/hr");
  
  List<String> Oven = new ArrayList<String>();
  Oven.add("Power:2400w/hr");
  
  List<String> Refridgerator = new ArrayList<String>();
  Refridgerator.add("Power:180w/hr");
  
  List<String> WaterHeater = new ArrayList<String>();
  WaterHeater.add("Power:4000w/hr");

  listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), Light); // Header, Child data
  listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), Television);
  listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), Computer);
  listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), Fan);
  listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(5), Aircondition);
  listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(6), Oven);
  listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(7), Refridgerator);
  listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(7), WaterHeater);
  
  

  
          
 
  
   
 
  
  
  
  
 }
}
```

```js
MY NumerPicker CODE

public class Picktime extends MainActivity {
 NumberPicker np;
 TextView tv1;
 Button btn;
 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.picker_frag);
        
        np = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSet);
        
        
        np.setMinValue(1);
        np.setMaxValue(100);
        np.setWrapSelectorWheel(false); 
        
       
       
    
  np.setOnValueChangedListener(new OnValueChangeListener(){ 
  @Override
  public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   tv1.setText("Hr Used:" + ( np.getValue()));
  }
 });



I TRIED TO DO A GET INTENT BUT I HAVE NO IDEA WHERE TO DO I INPUT IT IN

     btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

             public void onClick(View arg0) {
              NumberPicker numPicker = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
                int x = numPicker.getValue();
                 Intent i = new Intent( Picktime.this,
                   MainActivity.class);
                 
                 i.putExtra("Value", x);
                 
                
                 startActivity(i);
             }
         });
    }
 

   
}
```

Comment: You can pass value through `Intent` using `putExtra` or you can save it to `SharedPreference`.

Comment: I had tried using get Intent but my textView in child requires convertView for its Id while I could not implement it in my MainActivity.class. Thank much for helping

Answer (score 0):

Insert this in MainActivity Class, after onCreate method:

First, get the intent which has started your activity using the getIntent() method:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```

If your extra data is represented as string, then you can use intent.getStringExtra(String name) method.
In your case: It is int, so use

```
Integer in = intent.getIntExtra("Value",defaultValue);
```

defaultvalue is in integer.

Comment: I had tried using get Intent but my textView in child requires convertView for its Id while I could not implement it in my MainActivity.class. Thank much for helping